# Should we synchronize blockchain from scratch after every scheduled hard fork?

Tags: blockchain, hard-fork, synchronization

Should we synchronize blockchain from scratch after every scheduled hardfork or just update the binaries and synchronizing blockchain from where it was synced with pre hardfork binaries?

Answer (score 5):

I think generally just update the binaries and sync from where you left off. I believe the resync from scratch with the most recent binaries (v0.10) were due to significant changes to the database format, and resyncing was generally faster than converting the old one.

Answer (score 3):

No, we shouldn't have to resynchronize from scratch as it would create moments in the monero network where there are fewer functioning copies of the blockchain.

Imagine - if everyone sync'd from scratch at the same time, who would they be synchronizing from?

Hopefully this is the last major database reformat.

Comment: Hopefully pruning will be possible soon as database upgrades is to be expected going into the future.